# DRY IDisposable Pattern

Tags: c#, design-patterns, dry, idisposable

A lot of my classes repeat the below code to implement IDisposable.  This seems to violate the DRY (Don't Repeat Yourself) principle.  I could avoid some of the work by creating an `AbstractDisposable` base class, but that seems inappropriate / wouldn't work if I needed to extend other existing objects (assuming those objects weren't themselves disposable).

Another option would be to use a template/meta language where I could specify lists of managed and unmanaged resources for each class and have the generic Dispose Pattern auto generated when I build my project - but so far I've not played with meta languages / this seems extreme for such a common scenario.

```
public class SomeDisposableClass : IDisposable
{
    IDisposable _something; //a managed resource (unique to this class / here for illustration)

    /* ... loads of code unique to this class ... */

    #region Dispose Pattern
    private bool _disposed = false;

    ~SomeDisposableClass()
    {
        Dispose(false);
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        Dispose(true);
        GC.SuppressFinalize(this);
    }

    protected virtual void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        // Check to see if Dispose has already been called. 
        if (!this._disposed)
        {
            if (disposing)
            {
                // Dispose managed resources.
                if (this._something!=null) this._something.Dispose(); //(unique to this class / here for illustration)
            }
            // Clean up any unmanaged resources
            this._disposed = true;
        }
    }
    #endregion
}
```

Is there a good way to implement a suitable Dispose pattern without violating the DRY principle?

Comment: Avoid `IDisposable` like the plague. Because it spreads like one throughout your code base. And if you don't have unmanaged resources in your class, you can greatly simplify this code: `public void Dispose()
    { if (this._disposed) return; /* Dispose managed resources*/ _disposed = true; }`

Comment: @DanielHilgarth - I'm in favor of the simplification but following the MS pattern is usually mandatory. And do watch for glitches with derived classes when simplifying.

Comment: @HenkHolterman: I once found a very nice blog post from a respected member of the .NET community that detailed why the recommendation is at least outdated. Unfortunately, I forgot who it was. Following MS patterns is not mandatory. It is a good idea to strongly consider doing so, but if they are bad advice (or just bloated), you can freely decide to not follow them. Finally: Good point about derived classes. My main point in the comment was about getting rid of all the code required to correctly handle freeing the unmanaged resources like the finalizer.

Comment: @DanielHilgarth thanks for the suggestion.  FYI: I use the `using` keyword a lot in my code since I like the structured scope this provides (as opposed to calling Dispose() independently later on / worry about disposing in both `try` and `finally` blocks.  To use that I need to use IDisposable.  In my opinion the pros outweigh the cons there - but I could be wrong. . .

Comment: @DanielHilgarth Good shout on the second comment - that does seem more efficient.

Comment: @HenkHolterman: I think the post I was referring to was this one: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/29534/IDisposable-What-Your-Mother-Never-Told-You-About. John, it might be a good read for you, too, especially the discussion about Level 1 types.

Comment: @JohnLBevan: What kind of "structuring" are you talking about? I need `IDisposable` very rarely, so I am kind of wondering...

Comment: @DanielHilgarth Just the code's layout.  i.e. `using(IDisposableClass myObject = new DisposableClass()){/* ... */}` makes the scope of the object clear, whilst `IDisposable myObject = new DisposableClass(); /* ... */ myObject.Dispose();` feels less bounded / requires more effort to find the object's initialisation and dispose calls.  The "structured" argument is pure personal preference - though the `try{/*...*/} finally{/*...*/}` benefits of the using statement are more tangible arguments.

Comment: @JohnLBevan: I am not talking about `using` vs manually disposing. I am asking you, why your class needs `IDisposable` to begin with.

Comment: The practice of having general-purpose classes use finalizers/destructors for cleanup is no longer favored.  It's much better to move any resources which would require such cleanup into wrapper classes whose sole purpose is to manage the lifetime of those resources. Other objects could thus hold references to those wrapper objects without needing finalizer/disposers of their own (they should still implement `IDisposable.Dispose` and have it chain to the wrapper's dispose method, but not worry about "unmanaged" resource cleanup.

Comment: @supercat: That's basically the point of the CodeProject article I linked.

Comment: @DanielHilgarth: Any class `Foo` with a method or constructor that asks another entity to do something on its behalf to the detriment of others, and keep doing it until further notice, has a responsibility to ensure that that outside entity will be notified when their services are no longer required.  If `Foo` will need the entity's services as long as anything needs `Foo`, the only practical way it can carry out its responsibility will be to implement `IDisposable`.  Then when `Foo` is told that it's no longer needed, it can relay that message to the entity acting on its behalf.

Comment: @DanielHilgarth: Good article.  Missed the link until you re-mentioned it.  Thanks.

Comment: @supercat: I am not sure what you are trying to tell me with your long comment.

Comment: Thanks both. I assume [at]supercat's Foo comment was meant for me rather than @DanielHilgarth.  I'll read the article this evening, but the gist seems to be that the above pattern should still be used, but sparingly (i.e. only in dedicated managed resource wrapper classes), with the simpler Dispose() method (not full pattern) used to tell those wrappers when referencing objects no longer require their services.  If one of you guys sticks that as an official answer I'll give you ticks/upvotes so you can get points - thanks again.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I try to avoid `IDisposable` as best as I can. The problem is that it spreads throughout your code base. If a class has a disposable member, that class needs to implement IDisposable, too, etc.

Furthermore, `IDisposable` has problems when we are talking about type hierarchies.
A common scenario is to stick `IDisposable` onto a base class or even an interface if you think the derived classes need to free resources. However, most of the times, that's only an assumption and it really depends on the actual implementation if resource cleanup is needed or not, making the interface a leaky abstraction.
It would be better to only implement the interface if the class really needs it.
But this comes with its own problems:
How is the consumer of a certain interface supposed to know that the concrete instance he got - for example as a constructor parameter - needs to be disposed? He would have to explicitly check for it. And he would basically have to do this for every single instance of every non-sealed type he gets handed.

These are just two examples that show that you are best off to design your classes in a way so that they don't require the implementation of `IDisposable`.

However, if you really need to implement this interface, you should follow the Disposable Design Pattern as described by [this CodeProject article](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/29534/IDisposable-What-Your-Mother-Never-Told-You-About).

It basically divides your types into two levels:

- Level 0: Classes of level 0 contain only unmanaged resources, no managed ones. These classes need most of the usual default `IDisposable` pattern, although you don't have to implement the part that handles managed resources.
- Level 1: Classes of level 1 contain only managed resources, both of Level 0 and 1. These classes only need a simplified implementation of `IDisposable` because they don't contain unmanaged resources. The implementation basically just calls `Dispose` on each of its Level 0 and Level 1 members and on its base class.

Comment: Adding `IDisposable` when it turns out not to be needed is far less problematic than failing to add it when it turns out to be necessary. A method which is supposed to work with arbitrary implementations of non-generic `IEnumerable` is required to ensure that if an instance returned by `GetEnumerator()` implements `IDisposable`, that instance will not be abandoned without being `Dispose`d first. The fact that `GetEnumerator`'s return type (`IEnumerator`) doesn't implement `IDisposable` doesn't mean consumers don't have to call it; it just makes it awkward for them to do so.

Comment: `IEnumerator` and the objects contained in an `IEnumerable` are two different things.

Comment: My point was that the non-generic `IEnumerator` is a type which should have implemented `IDisposable` but didn't, and is used by any code which uses non-generic `IEnumerable`.  The fact that code which calls `GetEnumerator` must ensure that `Dispose` is called on any returned objects that require cleanup implies that the return type of that method should have inherited `IDisposable`. What is "infectious" is not the `IDisposable` interface itself, but rather the possibility that an object might be the only thing that would know when some other object that needs cleanup.

Comment: @supercat: I don't see why `IEnumerator` should have implemented `IDisposable`. When enumerating an `IEnumerable` you don't even actually use the enumerator in your code. And the objects returned by the enumerator might live a lot longer than the enumerator itself. I completely disagree with your assessment here. Following your argumentation, every single interface and every non-sealed class would have to implement `IDisposable` because a derived class *might* need to dispose of some objects.

Comment: Most kinds of enumerator don't require cleanup, but some do. Consider, for example, an iterator which performs a `yield return` within a lock. Not recommended, perhaps, but legal. If the code which creates the enumerator advances it to that particular `yield return` and decides it doesn't need it any more, the lock will be released if/when the enumerator is disposed. If the enumerator is abandoned without being disposed, the lock will be held forever.

Comment: @supercat: This sounds pretty contrived. And the solution is simple: Restructure your code. That's a whole lot better than making ***all*** interfaces derive from `IDisposable` - because that's the conclusion from your argumentation.

Comment: A type `X` should implement `IDisposable` if it it's conceivable that an instance derived from or implementing `X` might require cleanup *and* it's likely that last surviving reference to such an instance would be stored *in a variable of type `X`*. Many types satisfy the first criterion, but not the second. By contrast, I would guess that 99% of time when code calls `IEnumerable.GetEnumerator` the last surviving reference to the returned object will be stored in a variable of type `IEnumerator`.

Answer (score 1):

i don't think you are violating the DRY principle here. Because although you are disposing in each class but you are essentially not doing the same thing.,

Comment: Thanks @noone.  For me the issue is I've repeated a lot of boilerplate code; so whilst the objects being disposed may change this feels like a bad approach.  Better would be to have a way to refactor the code such that I create methods `DisposeManagedObjects()` and `DisposeUnmanagedObjects()` with the unique code in, and somehow have the class know the appropriate occasions to call these (i.e. without my having to add the associated boilerplate code).  Whilst slightly different to the concerns of DRY around normalisation of logic, I feel DRY also applies to general refactoring.