# Take on IDisposable pattern

Tags: c#, .net, memory-management, garbage-collection

OK, I've read a few things about best practices around IDisposable and I thing I basically get the idea (finally).

My question relates to inheriting from an IDisposable base class. All the examples i see write the same code blocks over and over in the sub-classes and i don't see the advantage.

Why not simply bake a virtual method into the base class, invoke it at the right time from inside the (privately implemented) IDisposable routine so that the sub-classes don't have all that clutter, yet still get a chance do manage their resources?

My proposed base class:

```
public abstract class DreamDisposableBase : IDisposable
{
    private bool _disposed = false;


    protected virtual void LocalDispose(bool disposing)
    {   
    }

    ~DreamDisposableBase()
    { 
        // finalizer being called implies two things:
        //  1. our dispose wasn't called (because we suppress it therein)
        //  2. we don't need to worry about managed resources; they're also subject to finalization

        // so....we need to call dispose with false, meaning dispose but only worry about *unmanaged* resources:

        dispose(false);
    }


    void IDisposable.Dispose()
    {
        dispose(true);  // true argument really just means that we're invoking it explicitly
    }


    private void dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        if (!_disposed)
        {
            // give sub-classes their chance to release their resources synchronously
            LocalDispose(disposing);

            if (disposing)
            { 
                // true path is our cue to release our private heap variables...
            }

            // do stuff outside of the conditional path which *always* needs to be done - release  unmanaged resources

            // tell .net framework we're done, don't bother with our finalizer - 
            GC.SuppressFinalize(this);

            // don't come back through here
            _disposed = true;
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: The disposing pattern demands that you make the Dispose(bool) method protected virtual.  So that derived classes can override it and call the base method.  Actually using the disposing pattern is wrong 99.9% of the time, writing a destructor is almost never the correct thing to do.  Framework classes have one, you should leave it up to them.  Like SafeHandle.

Comment: You're not improving over the standard pattern, just confusing things. Eg your SuppressFinalize is in the wrong place.

Comment: possible duplicate of [DRY IDisposable Pattern](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18361535/dry-idisposable-pattern)

Comment: A hugely helpful article for understanding IDisposeable objects (And why the "standard pattern" is actually not a good pattern) read the article "[IDisposable: What Your Mother Never Told You About Resource Deallocation](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/29534/IDisposable-What-Your-Mother-Never-Told-You-About)" written by [Stephen Cleary](http://stackoverflow.com/users/263693/stephen-cleary).

Answer (score 0):

You say:

> My question relates to inheriting from an IDisposable base class. All
>   the examples i see write the same code blocks over and over in the
>   sub-classes and i don't see the advantage.

That is not true, in the IDisposable pattern the method:

```
protected virtual void Dispose(bool disposing)
```

should be overrided by inheriting classes.

You need to note that the `Dispose(bool disposing)` method is actually your 
`LocalDisposing(bool disposing)` method. And this fact, I think, is the source of your confusion.

Please read the related section on the seminal book:
[Framework Design Guidelines, Second edition](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321545613)

Quoting the book:

> If you are inheriting from a class that already implements the
>   pattern, simply override the Dispose(bool) method to provide aditional
>   resource cleanup logic

In derived classes the code looks like:

```
protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
{
  if(disposing)
  {
      //release own resources
  } 
}
```

Also note that in this case you should call `GC.SuppressFinalize(this)` only in the non-virtual Dispose method.
Also in your code you are implementing the IDisposable interface implicitly, important to be aware of this.

Comment: If i take the tack of overriding `protected virtual void Dispose(bool disposing)...` in the sub-class, then i once again end up declaring, setting, and checking a `private bool _isDisposed` tracking variable. This is already done in the super class. That's pretty much what I was driving at. Why replicate the backing field and the conditional logic all over again? The base class knows all this already, so why not bake in a method that just gets invoked at the right time?

Comment: I don't know why you replicate the backing field, the Dispose receives an argument 'disposing' that you should use to control when release the resources. About the conditional logic Its just 'if (disposing)'.

Comment: That's a good point - my bad. It's just that nearly every answer (ahem, see Martin's) does so, so it has become part of what most people seem to think of as a standard implementation, but it seems redundant. If the base class tracks whether you've been disposed or not, why do it again? Thanks for staying with me, I'll buy in to the standard pattern.

Comment: You welcome, I also edit the answer to be more illusatrative. I recommend the book I cited in the answer because it makes you a better programmer.

Answer (score 0):

I do not see any real improvement in your code but as the pattern is non-standard it may be harder for other developers to understand it. To create a derived class using your pattern you need something like this:

```
class DerivedDreamDisposable : DreamDisposableBase
{
    protected override void LocalDispose(bool disposing)
    {
        if (disposing)
        {
            // Dispose aggregated objects that are disposable.
        }

        // Dispose unmanaged resources.

        _disposed = true;
        base.LocalDispose(disposing);
    }
}
```

Using the standard `IDisposable` pattern your derived class is something like this:

```
class DerivedDisposable : DisposableBase
{
    bool _disposed;

    protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        if (!_disposed)
        {
            if (disposing)
            {
                // Dispose aggregated objects that are disposable.
            }

            // Dispose unmanaged resources.

            _disposed = true;
        }
        base.Dispose(disposing);
    }
}
```

By deriving from `DreamDisposable` you avoid to replicate the field to keep track of the disposed state of the object. However, other than that the methods are effectively the same. Also, in your base class `LocalDispose` is empty and you have moved the code into the private `Dispose` method but that can be fixed by doing a small refactoring.

However, many classes will not have any unmanaged resources to release and because calling the `Dispose` method is idempotent (you can call it several times) you often do not have to keep track of the disposed state and your disposable code is simplified to:

```
protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
{
    if (disposing)
    {
        _child1.Dispose();
        _child2.Dispose();
    }
}
```

If you do not have any unmanaged resources in your inheritance hierarchy you do not need finalizer and the `disposing` parameter will always be true. Your `Dispose` method will then be:

```
protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
{
    _child1.Dispose();
    _child2.Dispose();
}
```

In general avoiding finalizers are good for performance which is why you call `GC.SuppressFinalize` to undo the harm you did by implement a finalizer.

But in many situations you still need to keep track of the disposed state of an object because you have to throw `ObjectDisposedException` if methods are invoked after the object has been disposed, and in that case my simplified `Disposed` methods is too simple. Here is an example on how to handle that without replicating the `_disposed` flag in each subclass and still use the standard dispose pattern:

```
class DisposableBase : IDisposable
{
    bool _disposed;

    ~DisposableBase()
    {
        Dispose(false);
        GC.SuppressFinalize(this);
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        if (_disposed)
           return;
        Dispose(true);
        _disposed = true;
    }

    public void DoStuff()
    {
        ThrowIfDisposed();
        // Now, do stuff ...
    }

    protected virtual void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        // Dispose resources ...
    }

    protected void ThrowIfDisposed()
    {
        if (_disposed)
            throw new ObjectDisposedException(GetType().FullName);
    }
}
```

Any derived class do not need to keep track of the disposed state and instead should use `ThrowIfDisposed` in all public methods that depends on the object not being disposed.

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't want every type to have a finalizer. The need to perform any work in a finalizer is very rare. Almost all implementations will not do anything if disposing is true. Finalizers hurt performance because they cause promotion to Gen2, need two collections to be cleaned and calling finalizers is single-threaded.

Most classes do not wrap unmanaged resources, and if they do they should use the `SafeHandle` types or others. That makes finalizers unnecessary as well.

Comment: Hugely helpful, I didn't understand the impact to performance. That's why I thought i'd just be super-safe and make sure Dispose was always called there. Cheers.